# Query a pair of X and Y with a list of X;Y

Tags: sql, oracle

We have;

| PositionId | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | -2 |
| 2 | -1 | -1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

I want to query positions in a list:

arg = [(-1;-2), (1;1)]

My expected:

| PositionId | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | -2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a multi-dimensional `IN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  (x,y) IN ((-1,-2), (1,1))
```

Or, if you are passing the `arg` as a string then use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TRANSLATE('[(-1;-2),(1;1)]', '[]', ',,') LIKE '%,(' || x || ';' || y || '),%'
```

Or, if the round brackets can be used as the term delimiter then it can be simpler:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  '[(-1;-2),(1;1)]' LIKE '%(' || x || ';' || y || ')%'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (PositionId, X, Y) AS
SELECT 1, -1, -2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, -1, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  1,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  1,  1 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| POSITIONID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | -2 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-0L0sapP)

Answer (score 0):

In case arg is a string, you may convert it's a list of numbers (x,y):

```
WITH data(positionid, x, y) AS (
    SELECT 1, -1, -2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, -1, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 1 FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL  
),
expr(s) AS (
    SELECT regexp_replace( '[(-1;-2), (1;1)]', '\[(.*)\]', '\1') FROM DUAL 
),
pairs(n, s) AS (
    SELECT LEVEL, TRIM(regexp_replace( TRIM(regexp_substr(s,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)) , '\((.*)\)', '\1')) as s
    FROM expr 
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(s,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
, lopairs(x,y) AS (
    SELECT x, y FROM (
        SELECT n, LEVEL AS c, TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(s,'[^;]+',1,LEVEL)) AS v
            FROM pairs
            CONNECT BY regexp_substr(s,'[^;]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL AND PRIOR n = n AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    )
    PIVOT (
        MAX(v) FOR c IN (1 AS x, 2 AS y)
    )    
)
SELECT positionid, x, y FROM data
WHERE (x,y) IN (
    SELECT x,y FROM lopairs
)
;
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated. You do not need to split the string and can just match a substring.

Comment: Of course you can simplify by using SUBSTR/INSTR for this case.